# Sending very long strings from MetaTrader 4 to Python backend using ZeroMQ Push/Pull Pattern

Tags: zeromq, mql4, metatrader4

I have a quite weird issue related to ZeroMQ messaging between MetaTrader 4 and a python backend.

The below shown code creates three strings which should be forwarded to a ZeroMQ `PUSH` socket. However, it only sends the `live_trades` string via the socket. Both the `account_info` and the `historical_trades` strings are not sent.

While debugging the weirdness only increased:

- When I print the `historical_trades` string, it is shown in the MT4 expert journal, but not in the MT4 log editor
- When I add `Print( historical_trades )` before or after the `pushSocket.send(StringFormat("%s", historical_trades, true));` it sends the string.

**Possible issues which I actually exclude:**

- The `PUSH` socket is too slow: I decreased the timer to 10 seconds and more, same result
- MT4 itself is too slow to create the strings: It prints them correctly, so it is fast enough
- The ZeroMQ `SNDHWM` ( HighWaterMark ) blocks the EA/socket from sending multiple strings in no time: Already increased it to 100 which should be more than sufficient

**Any other ideas I cannot verify with debugging:**

- The MT4 `Print()` function does some other stuff behind the scenes which enables the EA to send the string?
- Maybe there is a maximum string size in MT4 which blocks the string creation loop (my string is around 35.000 characters long). But then why does it work when I just `Print()` the string once within the `onTimer()` function?...
- Any chance that the account related information is not accessible on weekends?

**Or it is just my code which might be buggy..**

Any ideas much appreciated!

```
int OnInit()
  {
//---

   EventSetTimer(2);     // Set Second Timer as push intervall

   context.setBlocky(false);

   // Send data to PULL_PORT that consumer is listening to.
   Print("Connecting MT4 Dashex Feeder to Dashboard on Port " + IntegerToString(PUSH_PORT) + "..");
   pushSocket.connect(StringFormat("%s://%s:%d", ZEROMQ_PROTOCOL, HOSTNAME, PUSH_PORT));

   pushSocket.setSendHighWaterMark(100);
   pushSocket.setLinger(0); 

//---
   return(INIT_SUCCEEDED);
  }


//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Expert deinitialization function                                 |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void OnDeinit(const int reason)
{
//---

   Print("Disconnecting MT4 Dashex Feeder on Port " + IntegerToString(PUSH_PORT) + "..");
   pushSocket.disconnect(StringFormat("%s://%s:%d", ZEROMQ_PROTOCOL, HOSTNAME, PUSH_PORT));

   // Shutdown ZeroMQ Context
   context.shutdown();
   context.destroy(0);

   EventKillTimer();
}


//---

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Expert timer function                                             |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void OnTimer()
{

   /*
      1.) Account information
   */   

      string account_info = "";   
      account_info = account_info +

         "account_info|" +
         version + "|" +
         DID + "|" +
         IntegerToString(AccountNumber()) + "|" +
         AccountInfoString(ACCOUNT_COMPANY) + "|" +
         IntegerToString(AccountInfoInteger(ACCOUNT_LEVERAGE)) + "|" +
         DoubleToString(AccountInfoDouble(ACCOUNT_BALANCE),2) + "|" +
         DoubleToString(AccountInfoDouble(ACCOUNT_PROFIT),2) + "|" +
         DoubleToString(AccountInfoDouble(ACCOUNT_EQUITY),2) + "|" +
         DoubleToString(AccountInfoDouble(ACCOUNT_MARGIN),2) + "|" +
         DoubleToString(AccountInfoDouble(ACCOUNT_MARGIN_FREE),2) + "|" +
         DoubleToString(AccountInfoDouble(ACCOUNT_MARGIN_LEVEL),2) + "|" +
         AccountInfoString(ACCOUNT_CURRENCY) + "|" +
         IntegerToString(IsDemo()) + "|" +

         pushSocket.send(StringFormat("%s", account_info, true));
         Print("Pushing Account Information To Dashex.Finance Dashboard For Account No. " + IntegerToString(AccountNumber()));


//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+         

   /*
      2.) Pending and running trades
   */

      int live_orders = OrdersTotal();
      string live_trades = "";

      for(int i=live_orders; i >= 0; i--)
      {
         if(OrderSelect(i,SELECT_BY_POS)==false) continue;

           live_trades = live_trades +

           "live_trades|" +
           version + "|" +
           DID + "|" +
           IntegerToString(AccountNumber()) + "|" +
           IntegerToString(OrderTicket()) + "|" +
           TimeToString(OrderOpenTime(), TIME_DATE|TIME_SECONDS) + "|" +
           TimeToString(OrderCloseTime(), TIME_DATE|TIME_SECONDS) + "|" +
           IntegerToString(OrderType()) + "|" +
           DoubleToString(OrderLots(),2) + "|" +
           OrderSymbol() + "|" +
           DoubleToString(OrderOpenPrice(),5) + "|" +
           DoubleToString(OrderClosePrice(),5) + "|" +
           DoubleToString(OrderStopLoss(),5) + "|" +
           DoubleToString(OrderTakeProfit(),5) + "|" +
           DoubleToString(OrderCommission(),2) + "|" +
           DoubleToString(OrderSwap(),2) + "|" +
           DoubleToString(OrderProfit(),2) + "|" +
           "<" + OrderComment() + ">|";
      }

      pushSocket.send(StringFormat("%s", live_trades, true));
      Print("Pushing Live Trades To Dashex.Finance Dashboard For Account No. " + IntegerToString(AccountNumber()));

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+

   /*
      3.) History Trades      
   */


         int hstTotal = OrdersHistoryTotal();
         string historical_trades = "";

         Print(hstTotal);
         for(int i=hstTotal; i >= 0; i--)
         {

           if(OrderSelect(i,SELECT_BY_POS,MODE_HISTORY)==false) continue;

           historical_trades = historical_trades +

              "historical_trades|" +
              version + "|" +
              DID + "|" +
              IntegerToString(AccountNumber()) + "|" +
              IntegerToString(OrderTicket()) + "|" +
              TimeToString(OrderOpenTime(), TIME_DATE|TIME_SECONDS) + "|" +
              TimeToString(OrderCloseTime(), TIME_DATE|TIME_SECONDS) + "|" +
              IntegerToString(OrderType()) + "|" +
              DoubleToString(OrderLots(),2) + "|" +
              OrderSymbol() + "|" +
              DoubleToString(OrderOpenPrice(),5) + "|" +
              DoubleToString(OrderClosePrice(),5) + "|" +
              DoubleToString(OrderStopLoss(),5) + "|" +
              DoubleToString(OrderTakeProfit(),5) + "|" +
              DoubleToString(OrderCommission(),2) + "|" +
              DoubleToString(OrderSwap(),2) + "|" +
              DoubleToString(OrderProfit(),2) + "|" +
              "<" + OrderComment() + ">|"; 
         }

         pushSocket.send(StringFormat("%s", historical_trades, true));
         Print("Pushing History Trades To Dashex.Finance Dashboard For Account No. " + IntegerToString(AccountNumber()));

         Sleep(1);
}
```

**MetaTrader 4 log.editor:**

[image]

**MetaTrader 4 console:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Q** : *Any chance that the account related information is not accessible **on weekends?***

This has an easy proof: do a `Comment( aStringUnderTEST );` + check all account / Broker-related items.

---

> **Q** : *Maybe there is a **maximum string size** in MT4 which blocks the string creation loop...?*

This is, except a case of an MT4-Build-X.Y.Z release-bug awaiting a BugFIX, very low probability hypothesis.

Yet it has an easy proof: do a loop of growing string-lengths and test until what size the processing keeps working. The indirectly proved size-limit will help you track the root cause, MT4 not being the SPoF here, is it?

---

> **Q** : *The MT4 `Print` function does some other **stuff behind the scenes** which enables the EA to send the string?*

The MT4 Support ought be contacted if this is to get confirmed or denied. The software is licensed as an as-is product, so do not expect any rapid response or a rocket science to take place if you try to drill down to the bolts and nuts, inside their closed and sealed product.